# How to get sql before save

Tags: model, resource-model

I need to print the query before the save method in a model class. Is it possible?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved enabling log all queries in lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php

Comment: This is also possible without modifying core files, if you enable the Zend profiler in `app/etc/local.xml`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504931/how-do-i-print-all-the-queries-in-magento/6934364#6934364